# Statistics: Variance & Marginal Density Help

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

[image: Here is the problem]

I have to find the marginal density of X. Then, I need to find the variance of X.

My attempt: I think the marginal density is just the integral, which is **2x from 0 < x < 1**

**How do I find the variance?** I know there is this formula that uses the expected value, but I'm not sure how to proceed: Var(X) = E([X - E(X)]^2 )

Maybe something like E([2X - 1]^2)?

Answer (score 2):

Your pdf of $X$ is right. The variance can be calculated as

$Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$

In your case:

$Var(X)=\int_0^1 x^2\cdot f_X(x) \, dx-\left[\int_0^1 x\cdot f_X(x) \, dx\right]^2$

$Var(X)=\int_0^1 x^2\cdot 2x \, dx-\left[\int_0^1 x\cdot 2x \, dx\right]^2$

Comment: Tip: $\mathsf E(X^n)~=~ \int_0^1 2x^{n+1}\operatorname d x ~=~\dfrac {2}{n+2}$ (for any real $n> -2$)

Comment: @callculus why are we using fx(x) in calculating the expected values, and not just f(x)?

Comment: @HaroldFinch $f_x(x)$ is the marginal distribution $X$. It´s called marginal distribution because it is derived from the joint distribution. But it is the distribution of X.